# How can I query by sort key in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a database of users, and I'd like to return all users with the last name X. I currently have "last" as the sort key for my table. I'm running the following code, but getting a "Query condition missed key schema element" error.

```
var params = { TableName: 'Patients',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#id = :idNum',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { 
       '#id': 'last' 
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
      ':idNum': 'Test' 
    } 
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        res.json(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To query you must provide a partition key, so with your table, as it is, your only option would be to do a Scan (which is expensive and almost never recommended).

However you can easily add [Global Secondary Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) to allow you to use *another* key as your partition.

In this case you can add a GSI with `last` as your partition key.

Then you would be able to Query the *global secondary index* (note the [IndexName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property) parameter) by last name.

If you want to go the scan route, however, you'll need to use:

```
docClient.scan({
  TableName: 'Patients',
  FilterExpression: '#l = :l',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#l': 'last' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':l': 'Test' },
  Limit: 1
}, (err, data) => { /* callback */ })
```

Just remember that using scans can get expensive and put a strain on your table quickly ([more detail here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Limit))

Comment: Thanks for the response! If I decided to go the route of doing a scan instead, how would I modify my code?

Comment: No worries- I've added an example- although you really should avoid frequent scans on a dynamo db table if you possibly can.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'll take a look at the global index option as well.

Comment: Good luck! Don't forget to mark the question answered!

Comment: FYI, a GSI does not require the primary key to be unique, so you don't need to provide a sort key for a GSI. (Though it never hurts to add one.) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Comment: I actually did not know that- had just always assumed- cheers for the heads up @MatthewPope

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace what if my data is in a large amount and has more frequent operations, still would you suggest me to go with GSI? as I need projection with ALL attributes and I read on docs below
-------If you need to access most of the non-key attributes on a frequent basis, you can project these attributes—or even the entire base table— into a global secondary index. This gives you maximum flexibility. However, your storage cost would increase, or even double.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way DynamoDB/NoSQL should be used. You either create a GSI as thomasmichaelwallace suggested or have the users lastname as partition key too. You can add "ln_" before all of your last name partitionkeys to separte them from your other partition keys. If you had firstname as partitions before your primary key should look like that now:

```
partition | sort
fn_hans | ln_zimmer
fn_steve | ln_jobs
ln_zimmer | fn_hans
ln_jobs | fn_steve
```

Now you can query all partition which start with ln_. And yes you are supposed to have douplicate data in noSql. [NoSQL Design](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html) has some articles about how to design a dynamoDB table.